# Python: first instance of subprocess.Popen() is very slow

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but when using the subprocess module, there is a very significant wait (> 10 seconds) to starting the first subprocess. The second one starts shortly after the first. Is there any way to fix this? Code below:

EDIT: To add, HWAccess (in proc.py) links a dll. Could this have anything to do with it?
EDIT2: I've boiled the test down to starting a SINGLE subprocess and it takes significantly longer to import HWAccess than if I just run proc.py directly from cmd prompt. I don't see how this has anything to do with the dll specifically if it loads fast from cmd, but not as a sub-process through test.py

test.py:

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

print 'STARTING'
proc0 = subprocess.Popen(['python','proc.py','0'])
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['python','proc.py','1'])

while True: 
    try: pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    os._exit(0)
except ValueError: 
    pass
```

proc.py:

```
print 'Process starting...'
import HWAccess
print 'HWAccess imported...'
import sys
print 'sys imported...'
import time
print 'time imported...'

print 'hi from ',sys.argv[1]
```

Edit: After putting the prints in, there is around 5s to reach the first 'Process starting...', the second process prints 'Process starting...' immediately afterwards. Then there is a ~30 second pause to import HWAccess (takes a matter of seconds running on an individual process), the second process then immediately prints that it too has imported HWAccess... from then on execution is fast. HWAccess links a .dll so I'm wondering if two processes trying to import HWAccess result in some sort of race condition that takes a while to negotiate.

Comment: Why do you want to use subprocess to call another Python script? Use `import` to import your script.

Comment: There is nothing about your subprocess code which would cause the 10 second delay. Does HWAccess have any expensive or time-sensitive initialization? How long does `proc.py` take to reach the print when you run the script directly?

Comment: HWAccess is a collection of classes, but running as a normal process it imports rather quickly (instantiating one of the classes does take a bit, but I've put a print at the top of proc.py to check overhead of starting the sub-process).

Comment: Once HWAccess is imported, execution time from then on seems normal.

Comment: Actually it seems the majority of the startup time is in the 3 imports in the sub-processes.

Comment: And it is actually FAR more than 10 seconds. Should I wait for the first process to finish starting before spawning the second process?

Comment: Edited main post, HWAccess links a dll; could this have any odd consequences? Should I wait for the first process to finish initializing before spawning the second?

Comment: It sounds like its something about the dll itself.

Comment: So I added a sleep in between proc1 and proc2 creation, proc1 now starts immediately, so it definitely has something to do with both of them reaching for the same dll (or something about the dll). Is this something common to all dll's or just the one I'm using (google "teamfdi usbmpc" for the dll). If anyone knows I would gladly checkmark them.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what happens if you import HWAccess in the main process before spawning any child processes?

Comment: @kurumi: There are plenty of good reasons for executing Python code in a subprocess, especially if you want multiple independent copies of extension modules.

Comment: importing HWAccess in test.py doesn't help. If I put a sleep() in between the two Popen instantiations the time is drastically improved (but for benchmarking purposes I want the execution of each process to occur concurrently). Is there a way for me to pause a sub-process at a certain point from test.py, wait for the second process to finish importing, and then tell both to continue?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with python3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the right track, but I remember seeing such delays when starting a process wayyy back (and not at all Python related), and it turned out they were related to some badly configured network settings on my computer. Upon subprocess start-up, it has to set up interprocess communication, and those settings might interfere.

I remember my problems were related to using a false hostname for the machine, which was not properly configured on the network - can you check to see if it is your case? If it is not a production machine, try not setting a hostname at all, leaving it as "localhost".