# difficulty executing specific commands in python when not connected to network on a linux system

Tags: python, linux, networking

I'm puzzled by this one. If I'm connected to the network on a linux system everything works fine.  If disconnected I'm having trouble executing either of these sets of commands:

set #1:

```
cmd = 'cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm' 
args = shlex.split(cmd)
curr_alarm_sse,error = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

set #2:

```
curr_alarm_sse = commands.getoutput("cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm")
```

It isn't the cat command either, I tried to do a simple ls of my home directory, and in all cases the python script just locks up until I connect to the network again.  I have verified that it is locking up exactly at either of these command sets.  I'm puzzled because it doesn't seem like either of these command sets should be dependent on a network connection.  Am I wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: If you hit Ctrl-C while it's locked up to do a `KeyboardInterrupt`, what is the traceback?

Comment: @Nick ODell, when I hit Ctrl-C while it is locked up, python exits cleanly.  No KeyboardInterrupt, no traceback.

Comment: This could be related: [Python: first instance of subprocess.Popen() is very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399166/python-first-instance-of-subprocess-popen-is-very-slow). Note the answer says: *I remember seeing such delays when startignn process wayyyback (and not at all Python related), and it turned out they where related to some bad configured network settings on my computer. Upon subprocess startup, it has to setup interprocess communication, and those settings might interfere.*